# AngularJS ngOption does not display datas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'd like to use ng-options for my select using AngularJS but it seems not working as I'd like...

> Below you can see javascript code, which contain from creating array
>   and also view, where ng-options are using.

```
var vm = this;
vm.selectedUser;
vm.userDatas = [
  { id: 1, name: "Ruslan", surname: "Poltayev" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "Handor", surname: "Ten" }
];
```

---

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper" 
     data-ng-controller="TableShowCtrl as t">
  <select data-ng-model="t.selectedUser" 
          data-ng-options="item.name for item in t.userDatas track by item.id">
  </select>
</div>
```

---

> I have this results
>   [image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6xiH.png)

Comment: You have two levels in your json, so you can't access `item.id` or `item.name`. Can you change json structure?

Comment: What's the issue here

Comment: Your json objects are within an array of arrays. So you can't ng-repeat the root but you have to ng-repeat both or change the array by joining.

Comment: Sorry, I create incorrect array, I corrected it. But it does not work. `vm.userDatas = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Ruslan",
            surname: "Poltayev"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Ruslan",
            surname: "Poltayev"
        }
    ];` @YuriBlanc

Comment: you can't have two items with same id and use `track by`

Comment: Actually, I have response from the server with following datas, and even with them it does not work. `[{"id":1,"name":"Ruslan","surname":"Poltayev","createdAt":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Paris","location":{"country_code":"FR","latitude":48.86666,"longitude":2.33333,"comments":""}},"offset":7200,"timestamp":1470636724}},{"id":2,"name":"Handor","surname":"Ten","createdAt":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Paris","location":{"country_code":"FR","latitude":48.86666,"longitude":2.33333,"comments":""}},"offset":7200,"timestamp":1470636724}}]` @AlekseyL.

Comment: You can also look at array with responsed data by following this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9ucch7niyhotax/chrome_2016-08-08_10-22-58.png?dl=0)@AlekseyL.

Comment: @RuslanPoltaev Post repro in plunkr, so it will be easier to help you

Comment: @AlekseyL.Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtNmg0nzexR6bOUMP55t?p=preview)

Comment: @RuslanPoltaev you've put `ng-select` outside of controller's scope. [Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkTrlsPX4fh4mzjwV0Pg?p=preview) working example

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the  elements to display the different options. To display options using the name property you can use this:

```
<select ng-model="selected.user">
<option ng-repeat="item in t.userDatas">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>

<!-- display selected user -->
{{ t.selected.user | json }}
```

Comment: Sorry but I downvoted your anwer since the OP is using the **correct** way (which one is the use of `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat`) and you suggested a totally different thing.. it isn't being displayed because of another reason, not that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
<body ng-app="Sample">
<h1>Sample Angular controller</h1>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div id="page-content-wrapper" >
  <select ng-model="t.selectedUser" ng-options="item.name for item in usrDatas ">
  </select>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Script:

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("Sample",[]);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
  var vm = this;
vm.selectedUser;
$scope.userDatas = [  { id: 1, name: "Ruslan", surname: "Poltayev" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "Galym", surname: "Kariev" }];
})
```

[Working Demo at Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kQsrclf3bThcKSaxmAhF?p=preview)